# How to wait for Window content to resize before showing the window in C#?

Tags: c#

I have a webcam stream being display inside of a window in C#, and the webcam stream always shows up in a small size on the top left corner of the window before resizing to the window size. I have been trying to find a way only make the window visible only if the content has already been resized to prevent this "glitch" on resize.

I have tried only showing the content after the window is done resizing, but that does not solve the problem. I believe that the webcam stream is just not being fast enough to resize.

Is there a way to track that the window content is already ready to be displayed (is already resized)?

Comment: Set Visible to false and then to true.

Comment: it's difficult to help without any code to look at. Is this WPF, UWP, or Windows Forms?